# Update AMP Cache without RSA key or using 301 redirect

Tags: shopify, amp-html

According to https://developers.google.com/amp/cache/update-cache to update the AMP cache I need to generate an RSA Key and place it at:
https://example.com/.well-known/amphtml/apikey.pub

Unfortunately due to CMS restrictions (Shopify) that URL is not possible to set up.
Are there any other ways of updating the cache?

Would a 301 redirect work?
The file would be actually stored on the CDN, different domain, something like: https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/3201/2492/files/apikey.pub

Thank you

Comment: Do you remember if the 301 Redirect worked? I have the same issue (5 Years later)

Comment: Did some testing on my live site and I can confirm that the google bot that fetches the public key will follow the 301 from the .well-known folder. One other important tip is to include a ".txt" file extension when you upload the public key file to shopify so that Shopify will serve the file as "text/plain". For example https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1234/1234/1234/files/apikey.pub.txt

Answer (score 0):

I have used URL redirect (provided by Shopify) to link images in Outlook signatures. So yes, my guess is that it should work.

Try the following:

1. Place the RSA key in Google Drive (since Shopify will not allow .pub files as far as I am aware) - Don't forget make the file public so Google can access it.
2. Create a URL redirect linking the location of your RSA key with the link `https://example.com/.well-known/amphtml/apikey.pub`.

Let us know how it goes.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you Hamza, will set this up and see how it goes. Will probably take some time to  confirm due to Google index times

Comment: No worries @Mircea. Good luck! I will be waiting for your confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

You can also consider fetching the cached AMP page which also automatically updates the AMP cache (provided that your source content expires appropriately).

Comment: According to https://developers.google.com/amp/cache/update-cache, that method is the only way to clear the cache "on demand". Custom expire headers are also not possible on Shopify

Answer (score 0):

What Hamza suggested sounds like it might work, however, here is my recommendation:

Send the pub key and your reason for requiring it on the server to Shopify. If you have Shopify Plus, you will not be the first person requested things and they will accommodate you by placing the key at the desired location.

Sorry it is not more technical, but you are truly bound your CMS.

Comment: I've contacted Shopify support. The client is on Plus, but we got a "not possible"  message.

Comment: Really? Incredible. Need to escalate, or alternatively ask them to do it and include the steps.